# Any difference between `qcc -Vgcc_ntoaarch64le` and `aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc` when compiling?

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, qcc

Any difference between `qcc -Vgcc_ntoaarch64le`  and `aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc` when compiling? Are they equivalent?

As per the document, which says that:

> For example, this command:
>
> qcc -Vgcc,
> lists all targets in all versions of gcc. See the Examples section below for more examples.
>
> The targets include:
>
> gcc_ntoaarch64le
>
> gcc_ntoaarch64le_cxx
>
> gcc_ntoaarch64le_gpp
>
> gcc_ntoarmv7le
>
> gcc_ntoarmv7le_cxx
>
> gcc_ntoarmv7le_gpp
>
> gcc_ntox86 (default)
>
> gcc_ntox86_cxx
>
> gcc_ntox86_gpp
>
> gcc_ntox86_64
>
> gcc_ntox86_64_cxx
>
> gcc_ntox86_64_gpp

But I can't find any information about  `aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

`-Vgcc_ntoaarch64le` is just to configure the compiler.

Open the file `gcc_ntoaarch64le.conf`. In the host part, you can see `qcc` actually call `aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gccxxx`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Where can I find the said configuration file?